# Formula - Get sheet name using cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to compare a value in my current sheet with a value from another sheet in the same workbook. The name of the sheet can be found by getting values from two cells within my current sheet, but I cannot create a formula which combine cell values to a sheet name?

This is what I do instead

> =SUM(E25;-('0501F9011C00_1 Discard'!E25))

The value `0501F9011C00` can be found in my current sheet cell `B8`and the value `1`can be found in my current sheet cell `B10`

I tried solving it using a formula as follow, but it will not allow `!E25` in this formula

> =SUM(E25;-(CONCATENATE(B8;"_";B10;" Discard")!E25))

Is it possible to do what I try to do without using VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need `INDIRECT` which turns text into a cell reference.
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

It will probably be something like:
`=SUM(E25; -INDIRECT(B8 & " " & B10 & "Discard!E25"))`

Comment: Thanks, I only had to add `'` to your formula and now it works.
Working formula `=SUM(E25;-INDIRECT("'" & B8 & "_" & B10 & " Discard'!E25"))`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=INDIRECT(SUM(E25;-(CONCATENATE(B8;"_";B10;" Discard","!E25")))
```

***NOTE :*** `INDIRECT` is a volatile function. See [this](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) for details.